# Cassandra lots of GC on specific nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

Since we've upgraded our cassandra clusters from version 2.0.17 to 2.1.15, we're experiencing issues with 2 nodes from a 3 node cluster.

They are consistently using much more cpu than the other one. Closer investigation seems to indicate it's down to GC - when I track all 3 cassandra processes with jstat -gc, I can see that nodes 1 and 3 are GC'ing much more frequently than node 2.

This also shows from the cassandra logs, and the GCs seem to be quite slow on top of that:

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:17:35,655 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 210ms.  CMS Old Gen: 562659176 -> 612323584; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 49544256 -> 51445760
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:17:41,694 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 525ms.  CMS Old Gen: 612323584 -> 764506632; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:17:48,702 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 334ms.  CMS Old Gen: 823507232 -> 907859304; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 39578752 -> 51445760
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:17:58,667 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 369ms.  CMS Old Gen: 907859304 -> 1006118696; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:18:08,766 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 456ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1006118696 -> 1123833216; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:18:16,979 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 540ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1123833216 -> 1286209400; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:18:22,833 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 386ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1286209400 -> 1395049184; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:18:41,111 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 201ms.  CMS Old Gen: 801910056 -> 895733880; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:18:43,134 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 221ms.  CMS Old Gen: 895733880 -> 975905560; Par Eden Space: 411624624 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:22,733 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 214ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1030387520 -> 1079340184; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:31,430 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 266ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1079340184 -> 1166678176; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:35,061 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 606ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1166678176 -> 1353067264; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:37,808 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 2249ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1353067264 -> 477397536; Par Eden Space: 411936152 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 51445760 -> 0
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:48,769 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 362ms.  CMS Old Gen: 695828520 -> 793426632; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 40276928 -> 51445760
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:19:58,710 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 376ms.  CMS Old Gen: 793426632 -> 899121400; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:20:23,431 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 225ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1067967744 -> 1139648600; Par Eden Space: 411629080 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 40055056 -> 51445760
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:20:24,988 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 210ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1161527408 -> 1226340808; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:20:27,596 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 236ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1161527408 -> 477824664; Par Eden Space: 325760 -> 56800072; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-31 16:21:24,879 GCInspector.java:258 - ParNew GC in 574ms.  CMS Old Gen: 705116088 -> 868474072; Par Eden Space: 411959296 -> 0;
```

Increasing max heap and new heap from 1966M and 491M to 2500M and 1024M respectively seems to have little impact. Values were adjusted one by one, with `nodetool drain` and cassandra service restarts in between.

I've also tried taking all the load off this cluster, which does have effect on cassandra cpu usage - but nodes 1 and 3 keep using considerably more cpu.

The higher cpu usage is not constant - it goes back and forth between 'normal' and high, which seems to correlate with the GC runs.

I'm having trouble identifying what the cause might be and how to investigate this further. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is usual when you're looking at a problem that you think is a cassandra problem, it turned out to be our own fault. We had a bug in a process that caused it to constantly create, query and delete records for a single specific key. This meant it was creating a lot of tombstones and the queries were hitting increasing amounts of tombstones. The replication factor was also set to 2, explaining why it only affected 2 of the 3 nodes.

We've fixed the bug and CPU and RAM usage went back to normal levels immediately after deploying the fix.

Answer (score 2):

2.5gb heap is insanely small for a C* instance. Dont expect anything below 8gb to do much work without massive GCs, it simply wasnt designed for that. All things considering your 200-500ms gc every 5-10s or so is pretty good. 
see http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/planning/planningHardware.html#planningHardware__memory

> For both dedicated hardware and virtual environments, the recommended memory is:
>
> Production 32 GB to 512 GB; the minimum is 8 GB for Cassandra nodes.
>
> Development in non-loading testing environments: no less than 4 GB.
>
> Heap size is usually between ¼ and ½ of system memory.
>
> Cassandra automatically calculates the maximum heap size (MAX_HEAP_SIZE) based on this formula: `max(min(1/2 ram, 1024MB), min(1/4 ram, 8GB)`
>
> The recommended maximum heap size depends on which GC is used:
>   Older computers Typically 8 GB.
>   CMS for newer computers (8+ cores) with up to 256 GB RAM    No more 14 GB.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't around when the decision to go for C* was made here, nor for the VM size planning, and it hadn't occurred to me yet that that might be the issue as these clusters were pretty happy up until the upgrade. I'll try to figure out how it behaves with a more appropriate heap size ;)